# What is the best approach to create a service in Android?

Tags: android, http, android-service, httprequest

I wish to create service which starts running as soon as the app is installed. This service shall make http request after every 2 minutes. This service should be independent of the UI.
From one of the blogs I found this can be done using Service, Thread, IntentService and AsyncTask.

What should be the best approach?

Comment: use a alaram manager with service

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the [Google Cloud Message](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) tutorial. I think that should be the approach suggested by Google.

UPDATE: And in the [Android Services Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) too.